# How to add archive comment from a file or string?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, rar

I am writing a BASH script. I am using RAR 3.93 on Ubuntu 10.08. I want to add a comment to an archive example.rar. The comment is "This is a comment".

```
rar c example.rar
Processing archive rarcomment.rar
Reading comment from stdin
```

But I want to add the comment from a variale instead of typing it from the stdin.

```
$Comment="This is a comment"
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

```
    export COMMENT="This is a comment
with multiple lines"
    echo "$COMMENT" | rar c example.rar
```

To write multiple line variables, just don't close the quote until you are done. To make it append to the echo, use quotes.

Comment: Cool. What if I want to add a new line in the comment, like "This is a comment\nGlad it is working." Obviously, `\n` wont work.

Comment: I expanded the answer to illustrate this as well.